# Getting number format exception when accessing mysql from JDBC remotely

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I can access my remote database from the command line with users I create but when i try to connect from jdbc i get number format exception.

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://ipv6:3306/Library";
public static final String USER = "user";
public static final String PASSWORD = "correctpass";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

throws

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30a:2e1a:2470:7c29:300b:f757:2941:3306"'
```

I can login throw the terminal with the same credentials thats why im so confused. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That host in the URL is clearly wrong.  Doesn't matter if you can connect via terminal.  The JVM doesn't like it; fix it!

Comment: Sould you URL contain ipv6? then the first `:` must be `::`

Comment: Also early versions of the driver may not support ipv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would use IPV6 address to connect but it can be done.

```
public static final String urlString = “jdbc:mysql://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=your-ipv6-address)(port=3306)/Library”;
Class.forName(driver);
public static final String user= "user";
public static final String password= "correctpass";
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(getConnectionTimeOut());
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString,user,password);
```

Try above. Due to the reading address from mysql connection it was expect to have port read after the colon, and all ports are in numbers. Since you are not using standard address it would return you error as it tries to parse the port (all numbers as expected - but has letters so it hits number format exception). If you are using IPV6 you need to declare it as IPV6.

Comment: if i create i new user with access from my ipv4. I cant even login from the terminal. could that be a firewall issue?